# Deeper Understanding Mean Value Theorem. Show that $(1+x)^r>1+rx$

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification

Let $r>1$.

If

$$x>0 \text{ or } -1 \leq x<0,$$

show that $(x+1)^r>rx+1$,

This is what ive done:

$$f(x)=(x+1)^r-r x-1$$

$$\frac{d }{dx}-r+r (x+1)^{r-1}$$

From this I can see that if $-1\leq x<0$ then $f'(x)<0$, and if $x>0$ then $f'(x)>0$.

We already know that:$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(x),$$ this means that $f(x)-f(0)=(x-0) f'(x)$,

I can easily see that by plugging in zero into the function it spits out zero. But I might be confused because it is stated that given this information I should be able to see that $f(x)>f(0)=0$,

Now this is how I'm reasoning but I hope that someone could point it out if I am wrong:

I know if $f'(x) \cdot x$, where $x <0$, gives a positive value (negative times negative).

And for $x>0$ we get positive (positive times positive)

And in both these cases 
$f(x)>f(0)=0$,  if $x>0$ or $-1 \leq x<0$

If my reasoning is correct so far then this is my next step,

Since I have proved that

$f(x)=(x+1)^r-r x-1>0$, I can rearrange and get $(x+1)^r>rx+1$.

**This is what I am interested to know**, is my reasoning correct. And could someone explain the underlying theory with regards to this example.

I see that there is at least one point on the interval where the tangent line to that point is parallel to the chord line, but if it was not for the fact that I knew that I had to use the theorem I would not be able to solve this question.

**The book uses this explanation for the MVT**.[image]

But I do not see the logic regarding: show that $(x+1)^r>\text{rx}+1$.

**Stupid but important to understand is**: So what if the slope at one point is equal to the slope of the chord line?

But I just dont get it!

Comment: I fixed the title to reflect what's being asked in the question (the title used $1-x$ where the question clearly uses $1+x$, and the form used in the text with the $1$ on the right is much more familiar)

Comment: You may be interested to know that the inequality is called Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Would you be able to verify that what is written in the answer provided is correct cause I just do not get it.

Comment: I assume you're enrolled in a class somewhere. Your teacher will be happy to let you know whether the answer provided is correct.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Unfortunately not Im studying it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x) \colon= (1+x)^r$$ for all $x \geq 1$, where $r > 1$ is arbitrary but fixed.

Then $f(0) = 1$, and $$f^\prime(x) = r (1+x)^{r-1}$$ for all $x \geq 1$.

Now since $r > 1 $, we see that $f^\prime(x) > 0$ for all $x > -1$.

Moreover, by the Mean Value Theorem, we have, for any $x \geq -1$, the relation  $$ f(x) - f(0) = x \cdot f^\prime(x_0)$$ for some $x_0$ strictly between $0$ and $x$.

That is, for any $x \geq -1$, we have $$ (1+x)^r - 1 = x \cdot r (1+x_0)^{r-1}.$$

Now I hope you would be able to arrive at the answer to your question. Good luck!

Comment: For the function f(x), we have that x>=1,but then you define f(0) wish is less than the range specified,  and then we have for the mean value theory where there is a x>=-1, I just do not understand.

Comment: Would you be able to explain a bit more, I get really confused with the intervals used. I tried to make sense by plotting the graph but I was still unable to see what was going on.